# how to return iterator from a member function?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I have a template class like below

```
  template <class Key, class Object>
  class  TObjectRegistery
  {
  public:
     typedef map<const Key,  Object*> ObjectMap;

     void AddObject(Object *obj){
        objectMap_[obj.code()] = obj;
     }
  private:
     ObjectMap  objectMap_;
     }
```

I want to run an iteration outside of `TFactory`, then I want to add two member functions to the class.

```
  ObjectMap::iterator xbegin(){
     return objectMap_.begin();
  }
```

but I get an error that I'm missing ; before xbegin like undefine ObjectMap::iterator

```
  "missing ';' before identifier 'xbegin'"
```

why does this happen?
how I can fix it ?
if this good way to do iteration out of class?

Comment: `return objectMap_.begin();` missed the `;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need the typename keyword before ObjectMap, since it's derived type of the template parameters:

```
typename ObjectMap::iterator xbegin(){
    return objectMap_.begin();
}
```